# Check for duplicate name before adding in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two issues:

1. I want user to add the values in the dropdown but before that I am checking if the value is already present in that using this function:

   ```
    function IsNameAlreadyPresent(List,Name){
        $.each($("'#'+List option"),function(i,e){
            if(e.innerHTML == Name){
               return true;
          }
      });
    }


    function AddOptionName() {
       var Name = $("#txtName").val(); 
       if(IsNameAlreadyPresent(List,Name)) {
            alert("Name \"" + Name + "\" already exists. \nPlease type an unique name.")
         }
       else{       
               AddNewOption(Name);
           }
    }
   ```

I want to use this same function many times in my code to check whether the value entered is unique or not by passing the id of the dropdown and the name to be entered. but somehow this doesnt work.

how to pass the id as a parameter `($("'#'+List option")`?

2. I am using the same function to edit the text of the option as well. but somehow if the user clicks edit and he doesnt want to change the text and clicks OK it gives an alert that the option is already present.
   The option is only once including the one open in the popup. how to check this ?

   ```
    var x = document.getElementById("List");
        var l_sName = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
      $("#List option[value="+l_sName+"]").remove();
   ```

Comment: `$("'#"+List+" option")`

Comment: @depperm I think you mean: `$("#"+List+" option")` an apostrophe snuck in.

Comment: i got this but the check fails and it doesnt give alert but adds duplicates in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your selector is wrong, it should be `$("#"+List+" option")`. Also `return` inside `$.each()` will not return from your function, but break `$.each()` if false. Change your  `IsNameAlreadyPresent(List,Name)` to this:

   ```
   function IsNameAlreadyPresent(List, Name) {
       var result = false;
       $.each($("#"+List+" option"), function (i, e) {
           if (e.innerHTML == Name) {
               result = true;
               return false;
           }
       });
       return result;
   }
   ```
2. For this part you can add a name to be excluded for checking, for example:

   ```
   function IsNameAlreadyPresent(List, Name, Excluded) {
       var result = false;
       $.each($("#"+List+" option"), function (i, e) {
           if (e.innerHTML == Name && e.innerHTML != Excluded) {
               result = true;
               return false;
           }
       });
       return result;
   }

   function AddOptionName(Excluded = "") {
       var Name = $("#txtName").val();
       if (IsNameAlreadyPresent(List, Name, Excluded)) {
           alert("Name \"" + Name + "\" already exists. \nPlease type an unique name.")
       } else {
           AddNewOption(Name);
       }
   }
   ```

   and then call it with `AddOptionName( $("#"+List+" option:selected").html() );`

Comment: I tried removing the option when I click edit, but its not removing. 
Added the code in the question. Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: but the excluded and Name will be same. how will this check pass

Comment: You call it with an argument only when editing. Editing to the same value will then be allowed, but adding new names already present with `AddOptionName()` won't be.

Comment: Can you please explain it more clearly. I am not understanding what exactly to do?

Comment: how to call this in HTML ? AddOptionName( $("#"+List+" option:selected").html() );

Comment: @PSDebugger I think it will be easier to help you if you upload a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with all code, i.e. including html and the editing parts

Comment: how can we add a condition where it just excludes the text which is open for editing